# If I install Fedora 22 Workstation, will it eventually upgrade to the stable release?

Tags: fedora

The beta version of Fedora 22 Workstation has been released.

If I install this on my desktop, and keep it up to date, will I eventually end up with the same version of Fedora as if I had waited for the official release?

I understand that it's a beta and comes with inherent risks etc.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer I was looking for  [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrading_from_pre-release_to_final)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will end up with release version:

> You shouldn't need to do anything to get the final public release, other than install package updates as they become available. You can use "yum update" or wait for desktop notification.

For more info you can check following links:

- [Upgrading from pre-release to final](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrading_from_pre-release_to_final).
- [Updates Policy](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Updates_Policy).